# SendGrid dynamicTemplateData - HTML content and plaintext content in one email?

Tags: node.js, email, sendgrid

I'm trying to figure out how to send a plain text version of my email, alongside the html content generated by dynamicTemplateData and my dynamic template.

Including `text` as a sibling to `dynamicTemplateData` results in a broken email.

It looks like SendGrid is including a `text/plain` email alongside the `text/html` content, but it's empty.

Does anybody know how to inject a `text/plain` version of my email?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

When you preview your dynamic template, you can check it out in Desktop, Mobile and Plain Text versions. You can set SendGrid to automatically create a plain text version of the email from your HTML variant, or you can choose to write your own plain text version.

See the screenshot below for more detail:

[image]